# Display Results Manually eZ publish

Tags: php, string, ezpublish

I have this object attribute.
actually this is a checbox.

[image]

how can I get the attribute 0? and display its result?

`{attribute_result_gui view=info attribute=someattribute}`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to solve my problem..

here's the code for me to see the result of an attribute.

`X` is there signifies the `0` below the attribute...

`{$collection.attributes.X}`

so it'll look like this.

`{attribute_result_gui view=info attribute=$collection.attributes.0}`

Comment: or just:
{$collection.attributes.0.data_int}